# How do I distinguish a global variable from a local one with the same name in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin, and in my project I have something like the following

Utils.kt:

```
var weightInKilos = 100.0

//should multiply the above var
fun doSomething(multiplier: Double, weightInKilos: Double) {
    weightInKilos = weightInKilos * multiplier
}

print(doSomething(4.2, weightInKilos))
```

This would be the entire file (it's not part of an object,) so I can't use the this keyword. I know I could just rename one of them but is there some kind of identifier I can use to distinguish the two vars so the code prints 420?

Answer (score 4):

Use the package name as the identifier. If the enclosing package for `Utils.kt` file is `com.example`, you would use `com.example.weightInKilos = weightInKilos * multiplier`.

Thank you Android Studio autocomplete.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible outside of the class/object scope? In my testing, the `com.example.weightInKilos` results in an unresolved reference..

Comment: @TimMalseed absolutely.  Variables and functions can exist outside of class bodies in kotlin.

Comment: @Tom I'm not suggesting they can't exist outside of class bodies - but in my testing I can't reference these variables by package name. Edit: I stand corrected, I must have had the package name wrong.